# Should the blog index page be optimised for structured data as well as individual article pages?

Tags: blogs, schema.org

There are many tutorials out there that outline how to apply structured data to blog articles such as this one: http://edusagar.com/articles/view/72/how-to-add-microdata-to-markup-structured-data-in-your-blog

But one question I've always had, and have never been able to find an answer is what about the blog index page, where the excerpts for each blog article is shown on one page?

How should these be marked up, if at all, using structured data?

Is it okay to have several `blogPosting` schemas on one page for each blog article? Because this is what I have currently.

But should I just applying structured data to the individual blog article pages, and not having anything on the index page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that’s the purpose of the [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) type and its [`blogPost`](http://schema.org/blogPost) property.

On a page listing one or multiple blog posts (semantically it doesn’t matter if these are full posts or just teasers), each blog post can be represented by a [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) item which gets referenced via the `blogPost` property by the `Blog` item.

With Microdata it could look like this:

```html
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
  <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
  <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
  <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
</section>
```

If you *should* do this can’t be answered by us. There are no requirements involved unless you have specific consumers and their expectations/rules in mind (in which case you should consult their documentation).

In general, the best practice is to be as expressive as possible. The more structured data, the better. But if you don’t want to be as expressive as in the above example, you could omit the `Blog` item and just list the `BlogPosting` items on their own:

```html
<section>
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"></article>
</section>
```

But then the blog posts don’t have any relationship, and it’s not clear anymore that they are part of the same blog, and you can’t give any metadata for the blog (e.g., its title).